# Can we use discrete symmetry in order to generate neutrino mass in two higgs doublet model?

Tags: particle-physics, field-theory, neutrinos, higgs, gauge

It is seen that an u(1) symmetry is generally used to explain the seesaw mechanism for neutrino mass in 2HDM.it is used because the theory then naturally predicts the existence of a right handed neutrino. But is it possible to apply z2 discrete symmetry to explain the neutrino mass? If possible then how?